# Iterate through each XML file

Tags: python, xml, path, reportportal

So currently i have a code that passed the information to Report Portal from a XML file, this xml file located on its own folder and it applies to many folder. Currently, the parser only pass the last xml data that are stored in the memory even though it recognize all the other file

this is my code for now:

```py
launch = service.start_launch(name=launch_name,
                              attributes=rp_attributes,
                              start_time=timestamp(),
                              description=launch_doc)

r_path='\\\\esw-fs01\\esw_niagara_no_bck\\BuildResults\\master\\0.1.52.68_390534\\installation_area\\autotestlogs_top'

root = os.listdir(r_path)

for entry in root:
    subdir_path = os.path.join(r_path, entry) #  create the absolute path of the subdir
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):  # check if it is a folder
        subdir_entries = os.listdir(subdir_path)  # get the content of the subdir
        for subentry in subdir_entries:
            if subentry.endswith('.xml'):
                subentry_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, subentry)

                tree = ET.parse(subentry_path)
                root=tree.getroot()


for subentry_path in root.iter('entry'):
    if subentry_path.get('type') == "TM":
        if suite_item_id != None:
            service.finish_test_item(item_id=suite_item_id, end_time=timestamp(), status=tm_verdict)
        suite=subentry_path.find('name').text
        description=subentry_path.find('messages').text
        verdict=subentry_path.find('verdict').text
        if verdict=="True":
            tm_verdict="PASSED"
        elif verdict=="False":
            tm_verdict="FAILED"
        suite_item_id = service.start_test_item(name=suite,
                                  description=description,
                                  attributes=rp_attributes,                                  
                                  start_time=timestamp(),
                                  item_type="SUITE")
    if subentry_path.get('type') == "TR":
        name    = subentry_path.find('name').text 
        verdict = subentry_path.find('verdict').text
        link    = subentry_path.find('link').text
        duration = 10
        description = subentry_path.find('messages').text
        if verdict=="True":
            verdict="PASSED"
        elif verdict=="False":
            verdict="FAILED"
        start_time=timestamp()
        item_id = service.start_test_item(name=name,
                                        description=description,
                                        start_time=start_time,
                                        parent_item_id=suite_item_id,
                                        item_type="STEP",
                                        parameters={"key1": "val1",
                                                    "key2": "val2"})
```

the goal is to make it read all the files, any help will be apreciated

Comment: First off, I think you can considerably simplify the first loop by using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) or [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: Is there something missing? I don't understand how that would work, if `root = os.listdir(r_path)`, then `root.iter()` should throw an error, lists don't have an `iter` method.

Comment: oops forgot to include the tree and root definition. Its now added, its currently works by doing it this way but it only retrieve the data from the last file

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense! :) So in your first loop, you go through all your xml files and store them as `tree`/`root`. However, you don't do anything with them in this loop. In the second loop, you only work with the very last elements from the first loop that are still stored in `tree`/`root`. You need to indent the second for loop so it gets executed inside the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first build a list of paths, then in the second loop parse the files.

```py
# don't use 'root' here
src = os.listdir(r_path)
files = list()

for entry in src:
    subdir_path = os.path.join(r_path, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        subdir_entries = os.listdir(subdir_path)
        for subentry in subdir_entries:
            if subentry.endswith('.xml'):
                subentry_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, subentry)
                files.append(subentry_path)


for f in files:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for subentry_path in root.iter('entry'):
        ...
```

As a side note, it's advisable to use something more canonical to get all the files, like `glob`:

```py
import glob

filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(rpath, "**/*.xml"), recursive=True)
```

`filelist` is now a list of paths to all the xml files in the source directory. This will save you a couple of lines and indentations.

Comment: i tried this before, it still hasnt solve the problem of only reading the last files

Comment: Maybe you can try to implement `glob` as I outlined and simplify your code, then update your question. Right now it's quite hard to tell what the problem is. Also might have something to do with the `service` part but I never used that before.

Comment: the problem is still the same, its not passing all the files data but only the last files in the memory. and also when i use the glob, it makes all the process slower by much.

Comment: Don't know about the speed of `glob`. I updated my answer to make it a bit easier to implement. If that doesn't solve it, the problem is not about how you collect the files but something else downstream.

Comment: thanks, it now solved the problem. It just the matter on how i categorize it based on the folder name, so like a level up. Maybe you know how?

Comment: @Rafael Aditama Glad it worked eventually! Do you mean the `subentry` part? I didn't consider that in my answer indeed. A simple, but ugly solution would be to use `files.append((subentry, subentry_path))` and in the final loop, `for subentry,f in files:`. But if you can, give `os.walk` a try. At second glance it seems much more adequate here than the `glob` I proposed before!